# Which early game NPC is the better pack mule?

Tags: fallout-4

In general when I play RPGs I tend to be a bit of a kleptomaniac and a bit of a pack rat.  So, of course Fallout 4's crafting system that leaves nothing to waste is enabling this behavior even further.

I have discovered that Dogmeat can carry a bunch of my junk, allowing me to range further and for longer, but is he the best choice?  Can Codsworth or Preston carry more?  I can find no number in the game enumerating their actual carry limit before it gets reached.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically Dogmeat is the best choice if you just want a pack mule, because he doesn't count for the [Lone Wanderer](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lone_Wanderer_%28perk%29) perk. That means you can skill the perk and use Dogmeat, but still profit from the 50/100 additional carryweight which enables you to carry a lot more than you could with another follower.

Dogmeats own carryweight is 150 lbs, which is the same as codsworth and just a little bit less than npcs like preston garvey. Together with that perk on lvl 2, you can carry an additional 250 lbs. The only NPC which can outweigh that bonus is Strong, the super mutant, who can carry 270 lbs, but you lose the other advantages of the lone wanderer and only gain 20lbs more carryweight.

Comment: Where on earth did you find that information?  I've looked and looked but haven't been able to find an actual number.

Comment: I played a lot of Fallout 4 myself already. Also, reddit is always a good source of information, and the fallout 4 wiki is updated daily.

Comment: Thanks.  It turned out that I had to perform a system upgrade to play the game, so I'm getting a late start myself.  I'll keep an eye on reddit as well.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that the fact that Dogmeat doesn't count for the Lone Wanderer perk could be a bug as one of the loading tips supposedly mentions that Dogmeat counts as a regular companion.

Comment: @Lilienthal I think this mechanic should make up for his drawbacks (melee, can't wear stronger weapons). Also, he always has 1000 affection, doesnt care which faction you join and so on. I don't think that he counts as a regular follower.

Comment: according to this wikia page: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_companions it is a bug that dogmeat doesn't count as a companion.

Comment: @Buzz Too bad ... Guess I'll need to look into modding then to keep this "bugged" state.

Comment: @YUNOWORK i'd rather have a mod that takes his companion status away so that you can have one companion and a dog. if they take away the fact that he doesn't count for that perk there is no benefit to using him at all.